1970s or 1980s UK scifi movie with alien slugs?
I'm looking for a movie (or TV episode?) I saw on TV at least 30 years ago!
Here's what I remember:
Plot Details

there are these slow-moving grey slug monsters that make a weird sound.  There are many of them.
each monster is about the size of a medium-weight dog (Spaniel) and has a single tentacle in front
the characters are trapped in a small house, possibly in the countryside, and at one point one of the monsters smashes a window with its tentacle!

Production details

in color
UK production?  The actors were English
the monsters are rubbery: practical (pre-CGI) special effects
The production quality I would put somewhere between Baker-era Doctor Who and a Hammer Horror film... it may have been a Hammer Films Production for all I know!
Note that I saw it in the 1980s on TV, but it may have been made before that (back to the late 1960s, even)

Any leads are very welcome, this has been driving me crazy for years!

Welcome! And thanks for writing such a detailed ID question! I can't guarantee you'll get an answer but you've certainly made it easier for us!

Outrunning a slow moving slug wouldn't be hard...I'm almost thinking a scene from the original "War of the Worlds" here but some of the other details don't fit.

It's for sure not the 1953 War of the Worlds if that was what you are thinking.  This was daytime and the slugs were a sort of rubbery rock color!  The people had cornered themselves in this house.
You'd think people would just walk away from slow-moving monsters, but it's a problem people seem to run into a lot!  The Blob, Triffids, Zombies, The Creeping Terror...  all of them could be defeated by buying everyone some running shoes.  SPONSORED BY NIKE

Fiend Without a Face (1958) seems very similar except that it was made in black and white, not color. Are your certain that your movie/TV episode as in color?

oh man, I love those little jumping brain things!  No, it wasn't Fiend Without a Face.  @Walt here figured it out: it is Island of Terror (1966) starring Peter Cushing!  See below for a clip.

Sounds like the UK horror film Island of Terror from 1966 with Peter Cushing.

A small island community is overrun with creeping, blobbish, tentacled monsters which liquefy and digest the bones from living creatures. The community struggles to fight back.

The monsters resemble dog-sized slugs with one tentacle (see here) and at some point one of them breaks through a window of a countryside house, terrorizing the people inside. Here's the trailer:




You did it!  Those are the slugs!  "Silicates."  I have to say I'm impressed!
You know what's odd for me: I totally knew who Peter Cushing was when I was in high school... which means it's been more than 30 years since I saw this!  I remember not knowing the significance of the "silicates" name also, which means it was for sure before I took a Chemistry class.
